# Transfer response value to new request in soapUI free

Tags: groovy, soapui, sessionid

I have a log in request in soapUI and it returns a token in the response headers.

Using the groovy script:

```
       def value = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Login"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders     ["Set-Cookie"]
   re = /(token=[A-Za-z0-9]+)/
          matcher = ( value =~ re )
        def loginToken = matcher[0][0]

           testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Token", "$loginToken")
```

i have isolated the token but now i need to transfer that into a new request.

In the raw request line i have for this request i have:

```
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=c4or1i45pfafgn55mwt0im45; ASPSESSIONIDQATCRRQQ=LCHPHGHDGCFKNABDBCHCBEBG; ASPSESSIONIDSAQCSRQQ=OICNPHKCGIMLOANJEIIDPIBG; FleetCommon=ReadOnly=0; FleetCustomerLogin=AutoRefresh=3&VehicleFilter=0&VehicleFilterName=&CanImport=True&IsSupervisor=True&UserName=Leaselink+Dev+1&HasOpMaint=2&FranchiseFilter=&CustomerID=161&CustomerName=ALD&EMail=leaselink%2Ddev%40ebbon%2Ddacs%2Ecom&UseLookupCodes=False&OperatorInitials=LD&ReadOnly=0&OperatorID=%7B952E5028%2D38A5%2D454B%2DB65B%2D686507C00B19%7D; FleetLogin=CSOptions=0&Operator=Leaselink+Dev+1&SystemSide=Lease&IsNominated=&ServiceView=False; LLMembership=B279E049D39450F12456020DAA66A06E8104ACC73DBBCCF9F15AC684462B0FC93E45E68B3D28F4CC2CACA9C1D58C0C7990793681C173958C316F4043DC5C1B315DDDE8CB158AEF90C674992E17A5586390D4606FC59EBE19E662682A3D7CBA7D32BA56F1A1DECAEA63F31A36DC452AD3DB7AEF9FC0F83A9929BD001C57ED9984A1D5EAA6A9243877D6A6279F1BE661B01F5B2A00B1B018EDE36AB1E8D4C7E8C2EC47C24D5656473C22BB11446309E8FB00000000; token=0FnAwkKNLyvQMVyAn2eljO0yyuzxWXNWlqaDcIeXgC8kdZng7vGw
```

This last bit:

```
 token=0FnAwkKNLyvQMVyAn2eljO0yyuzxWXNWlqaDcIeXgC8kdZng7vGw
```

I need to replace with my own value from the first response. That response currently sits as a property for the test case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Comment: A +1 for you not because I had the same question as you, but because you already had code that I needed to solve my own issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is wondering I solved this issue by referencing where the property was in the testsuite.

I added a custom header of Cookie and set the value to:

```
{#Testcase#$Token}
```

I was overthinking it and when i'd read this previously i assumed "testcase" was meant to be the name of my testcase and was not literal.

Anyway thanks for helping!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
for (header in messageExchange.getResponseHeaders())
log.info header //<- prints all headers
```

I found this information on [soapUI's forum](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8631)